# Recommended Replacement for IronPython when using Robot Framework with .NET

Tags: python, .net, ironpython, robotframework

The Robot Framework user guide recommends using IronPython to run tests against .NET applications.  The only problem is that IronPython seems to be dying, given the last release was almost two years ago.  Are there any recommended replacements for IronPython when using Robot Framework with .NET?

I'm currently using CPython with Python for .NET (aka PythonNet).  It works but the data type conversion is a bit clunky: It automatically converts some data types, like integers, between Python and .NET, but others, like System.DateTime, it brings them through into Python as .NET data types.  The result is a lot of type conversion code in the user keywords, to be able to compare data read from the database with the data read from the .NET system under test.  It's annoying enough that I'm concerned users will be put off by the hassle and avoid using Robot Framework for testing.

**EDIT:**  A co-worker has pointed out that IronPython is still alive, and after almost two years they have recently dropped a new release (2.7.6).  So IronPython is still a valid choice for Robot Framework.

Comment: Post the update as an answer and accept it. Make sure you use Google before posting such questions. Usually a single search can give the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A co-worker has pointed out that IronPython is still alive, and after almost two years they have recently dropped a new release (2.7.6). So IronPython is still a valid choice for Robot Framework.